# ForEach loop is leaving my variable empty

Tags: powershell, foreach

Complete novice to Powershell so, my apologies ahead of time for the likely easy task for most in this group.

```
$File = Get-ChildItem "C:\location"
$ACLs= foreach ($item in $File) {get-acl $item.FullName}
$foldernames = $acls.pschildname
$ACLNames = $acls.Access.IdentityReference

$ACLNamesNew = foreach ($ACLName in $ACLNames) {
   $ACLNameString = $ACLname.Value.ToString()
   $ACLNameFormatted = $ACLNameString.Split("\")[0]
}
```

Ultimate goal is to take the string, trim just the domain/group names from the string, pull only the unique values, and write whats left to the variable $ACLNames. Haven't even tried filtering unique as even the above leaves $ACLNamesNew empty. The foreach seams sound from my testing, but it doesn't write the values into the variable as I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to collect the result of a loop you have to output something inside your loop. This should be enough .. if I've got you right

```
$fileList = Get-ChildItem 'C:\location'
$ACLList = foreach ($file in $fileList) { get-acl $file.FullName }
$ACLNameList = $ACLList.Access.IdentityReference

$ACLNameNewList = foreach ($ACLName in $ACLNameList) {
    $ACLname.Value.ToString().Split("\")[0]
}
$ACLNameNewList
```

Comment: As soon as I read "...have to output something..." the light bulb clicked.  The solution works, but the real answer is just that... output.  Cannot expect input into the variable if no output is generated.  Thank you Olaf!